# Mocking django tests - why is this patched function still being called?

Tags: python, django, django-models, mocking, django-unittest

I'm trying to test a function in one of my models, and am trying to to mock out the filesytem using `mock.patch`.  No matter what I try, it doesn't seem to intercept the method.

Model to test:

*app/models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from .utils.storageutils import get_file
from .utils.datautils import derive_data

Class DataThing(models.Model):
    #defined here

    def set_data_from_file(self):
        data = derive_data(get_file('filepath'))
        setattr(self, 'derived_data', data)
        self.save()
```

*app/utils/datautils.py*

```
import pandas as pd

def derive_data(data_from_file):
    df = pd.DataFrame('...')
    #do stuff with dataframe
    return df
```

*app/tests/unit_tests/tests_models.py*

```
from django.test import TestCase
import mock
from app.models import DataThing

class DataThingModelTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
      cls.datathing = DataThing

    @mock.patch('app.models.derive_data')
    def test_set_data_from_file(self, mocked_derive_data):
        mocked_derive_data.return_value=('pretend_dataframe')
        self.datathing.set_data_from_file()
        self.assertEquals(self.datathing.derived_data, 'pretend_dataframe')
```

I would expect this to pass.  However, I get an error, because `datathing.set_data_from_file()` is still ultimately calling `utils.storageutils.get_file`.  I've tried patching in `app.utils.datautils.derive_data` but have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also needed to patch the `get_file` function

```
@mock.patch('app.models.get_file')
@mock.patch('app.models.derive_data')
def test_set_data_from_file(self, mocked_derive_data, mocked_ger_file):
    mocked_get_file.return_value=('placeholder')
    mocked_derive_data.return_value=('pretend_dataframe')
    self.datathing.set_data_from_file()
    self.assertEquals(self.datathing.derived_data, 'pretend_dataframe')
```